# Symfony PHP Application not showing CSS and JS on browser

Tags: php, symfony

My PHP application is not showing css and js on the browser.
also it is not using ascetics. how can i use assets on my application?
Any help would be appreciated.Since apart from the official site not much content available on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You must dump your js and css files in Resources/public folder of your bundle.

After, see this page to know how to integrate your files in twig template :
http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

and finaly lauch this commands in your console :

```
php app/console assets:install web/
php app console assetic:dump
```

Comment: thanks @Fabien. Actually when i try to check the page resource, it shows the css and js files on the it.But they are not displaying on the browser.Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: you probably have a problem with your file inclusion in your view.
Do you use {% javascript %} and {% stylesheet %} tags same in my previous link ? (http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#assets)

Comment: can you please explain me how to use this {# ... #}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/acme_foo/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
{# ... #}

Comment: What you don't understand ?
 - you put your css in your [bundle]/Resources/public/css
 - You paste this in your template {% block stylesheets %} {% stylesheets 'bundles/[bundle]/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %} <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" /> {% endstylesheets %} {% endblock %} (your bundle name must be write in lowercase for this tag) - you launch the two commands of my answer and we could see your css file in web/bundle/[name_of_bundle]/css/your_files.css